# Redshift UDF compatibility issue

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to install a function mentioned on this page...

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Checksums/Verhoeff_Algorithm#plpgsql

It is working on all platforms except Redshift. I get an error...

```
Error in query: ERROR: Create Function is not supported for language plpgsql.
```

How do I make this function compatible with redshift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because plpgsql is NOT supported in Redshift.

What you CAN do in Redshift is explained here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html

I think that you will need to use a Redshift plpythonu function for this, you can see the python version of the code on the link that you posted. You just need to wrap that inside a plpythonu.